# Printing a Chosen Line from a File

Tags: python

How can I use Python to print a line of my choosing from a file?
E.g. a file 10 lines long and I use sys.argv to provide a value for the line that I wish to print.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far? Of all the things you've tried, why they didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = open('put_your_text_file.csv', 'r')
num = sys.argv[2]
for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
    if i == num:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Of course, I am assuming that the argument is the 3rd position (`sys.argv[2]`)

Comment: Could you provide an example of defining f? Guess this is pretty elementary but I'm pretty inexperienced. Thanks.